# Using global helper function in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have small functions which needs to be used in many components. These functions just do some calculations on data and return, and are independent of rest of app.
Should I put these functions in JS file at home directory or is there a Vue way to do this thing?

Comment: @AhmedHammad Shouldn't Vuex be used only for state management? The functions I am talking about are just helper functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your functions inside a global js file (for exemple 'functions.js'), or define them inside the main Vue's `methods` property:

```js
// functions.js
export function message(value) {
  return 'hello ' + value
}

// and/or

// main.js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>",
  methods: {
    superMessage(value) {
      return 'super hello ' + value 
    }
  }
});
```

Then use these functions inside any component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ message('world') }}</p> <!-- "hello world" -->
    <p>{{ $root.superMessage('world') }}</p> <!-- "super hello world" -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { message } from "./functions"
export default {
  methods: {
    message
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put these functions in the global JS file, but here are a few alternatives.

1. Define the function as a method of the parent Vue component, and  you can access it via `this.$parent.method();`.
2. You could use a Vuex store, which will definitely be easier if you have a lot of nested child components accessing the method.

   ```
   state: {
       data: 'hi',
   },
   getters: {
       data(state){
           return Array.from(state.data).reverse().join('');
       }
   }
   ```